# How to open a local file in a local software from a weblink on a local webhost

Tags: php, windows, wamp

I am running WAMP on my personal computer for a webapp I developed that I use. I wanted to know if it is possible to load a local piece of software from a hyperlink. The webapp will generate certain parameters and this is passed on to the software, which has a command line interface. I am aware that browsers generally do not have access to files located outside of their designated folder that serves webpages, but in this case, I would be generating parameters that are passed to a software. Thanks.

Comment: what local software are you using?

Comment: I want to open a video file into VLC.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **file:///** protocol if you want to link to local files.

Sample link:

```
<a href="file:///C:\MyVideo\sample.mp4">Open Local Video file</a>
```

Comment: This would be a good solution, but it is not exactly what the questioner asked about.

Comment: Also, it doesn't work. No modern browser will honor links to `file://` from a web page.